# Trying to apply this script to a specific div

Tags: javascript

Here's a [transition loader](https://github.com/amarinediary/Vanilla-JS-Pages-Transition-Loader) running while downloading an external mp3, waiting to be ready to stream with `<audio></audio>` tags inside a `<div class="player"></div>`.

How can I apply this script to the specific `<div class="player"></div>` only and not to the whole page? Thanks.

```
let e= {
  backgroundColor: "#fff", filterBrightness:2, strokeWidth:10, timeOnScreen:100
},
t=document.querySelector("*"),
r=document.createElement("style"),
i=document.createElement("<div>"),
s="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
n=document.createElementNS(s, "svg"),
o=document.createElementNS(s, "circle");
document.head.appendChild(r),
r.innerHTML="@keyframes swell{to{transform:rotate(360deg)}}",
i.setAttribute("style", "background-color:"+e.backgroundColor+";color:"+e.backgroundColor+";display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;position:fixed;top:0;height:100vh;width:100vw;z-index:2147483647"),
document.body.setAttribute("style", "overflow:hidden!important;"),
document.body.prepend(i),
n.setAttribute("style", "height:50px;filter:brightness("+e.filterBrightness+");animation:.3s swell infinite linear"),
n.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 100 100"),
i.prepend(n),
o.setAttribute("cx", "50"),
o.setAttribute("cy", "50"),
o.setAttribute("r", "35"),
o.setAttribute("fill", "none"),
o.setAttribute("stroke", "currentColor"),
o.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", "165 57"),
o.setAttribute("stroke-width", e.strokeWidth),
n.prepend(o),
t.style.pointerEvents="none",
t.style.userSelect="none",
t.style.cursor="wait",
window.onload=()=> {
  setTimeout(()=> {
      t.style.pointerEvents="", t.style.userSelect="", t.style.cursor="", i.remove(), document.body.setAttribute("style", "")
  }
  , e.timeOnScreen)
}
```

Comment: Did you try `t=document.querySelector(".myplayer")`?

Comment: Tried, but it does not work

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

You have a typo: `i = document.createElement("div"),` should not have `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert "myplayer" into a web component.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

```
class MyPlayer extends HTMLParagraphElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // Element functionality written in here 
    // ADD YOUR CODE HERE
  }
}

customElements.define("myplayer", MyPlayer);
```

This creates an HTML element that has code specific to its self.

Comment: I get: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': "player" is not a valid custom element name". (Please note that I changed my class name into "player")

Comment: It has to match the DIV in your DOM. customElements.define("This-Needs-To-Match", MyPlayer);

Comment: The DIV in my DOM is <div class="player"> and I'm using customElements.define("player", MyPlayer);

Comment: @rocco it's not going to be a class anymore, a web component creates a new HTMLElement and your define it in JS; <player> </player>

Comment: Anyway, these Custom Elements are amazing, I didn't know 'em before, and now new scenarios open up for me where to use them. Thanks Tom Hanks!